# How to scrape twitter followers ith scrapy and XPath?

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, twitter, scrapy

I am trying to write a Scrapy scraper to get to get all the followers of a given account (take mine, for example https://twitter.com/Acrocephalus/followers). Which is the XPath to the username (for example @ndlstrong) of my followers?
Thanks!

Dani

Comment: To get the XPath why don't you open the site in a browser, run a developer tool and look up the element in the HTML-tree?

Comment: Thanks GHajba, that's what I'm trying to do, but how do I code it into XPath? For example, class="u-linkComplex-target" contains the username, but I only need those whose class="FollowStatus" = follows you. How can I do it?

Comment: Why not use [`tweepy`](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.2.0/getting_started.html#hello-tweepy)?

Comment: Hi IanAuld. Wouldn't tweepy hit the Twitter API limits?

Comment: I am able to get all usernames using //span[@class="u-linkComplex-target"]. How can I restric the search to those with class="FollowStatus" = follows you?

Comment: If you have the element with the given class you can call XPath again on that element with the FollowStatus class to see if it returns something or not. This would be a solution. Alternatively you can combine those two queries and extend your XPath query to query the sub-nodes (currently I do not have access to twitter so I cannot look up the DOM and give better XPath descriptions).

Comment: Thanks GHajba. Now it's solved. I've been looking the code and it seems that non followers have a different class, so class="u-linkComplex-target is only for followers.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching and I've found that //span[@class="u-linkComplex-target"] retrieves the followers usernames. Non followers have a different class, so class="u-linkComplex-target is only for followers.